# TextView Shape background is not showing when text is large and is scrolling

Tags: android, textview, scrollview, shapes

This is the problem scenario:

I have an `Activity` including a `ScrollView`,
`ScrollView` has only one `LinearLayout` as a child and the `LinearLayout` has one `TextView`.
The XML file is here:

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/bubble_shape"
                android:text="@string/TestLargeText"/>
        </LinearLayout>

    </HorizontalScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

and the "bubble_shape" `drawable` is here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="15dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="15dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="15dp"
        android:topRightRadius="15dp"/>
    <padding
        android:bottom="12dp"
        android:left="12dp"
        android:right="12dp"
        android:top="12dp"/>
    <stroke
        android:width="8dp"
        android:color="#ff00ff"/>
</shape>
```

I have a large text in the `TextView` and here is the problem:
when the `TextView` has large text the background shape is not showing. You can see the problem in the pictures below:

[image: the xml file width small text]

[image: and the same xml width a large text!]

how can I solve the problem?

Comment: I copied your code into my IDE and did not have your issue. Maybe there is more going on here that you can share. As I cannot reproduce based on your code other than the width going off the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved your problem in two ways .

1- set "bubble_shape" to your `HorizontalScrollView`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/bubble_shape">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/TestLargeText" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </HorizontalScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

2- or just change corners tag in your "bubble_shape" like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <corners android:radius="15dp" />        

    <padding
        android:bottom="12dp"
        android:left="12dp"
        android:right="12dp"
        android:top="12dp" />


    <stroke
        android:width="8dp"
        android:color="#ff00ff" />
</shape>
```

Comment: Tanks @mohammadReza about your first solution I should say in my case is not good enough because I'm going to add more `TextView`es and I want them to be separate by the shape stroke. Your **second** solution solved my problem so amazingly and I still can't understand why this happens when I use radius for  corners separately. Do you have any idea about that?

Comment: dadash man harchi dar moredesh search zadam dalilesho nafahmidam! ag chizi dastam oomad too hamin post migam dalilesho ! zendebad finglish :)